# Preseed create two empty partitions ("do not use") with partman

Tags: partitioning, preseed

I have a question about preseeding. I need to create a simple partition table like this:

```
/    10 G EXT3         primary       
swap 8  G SWAP         primary
     100G "Do not use" primary (to be later used for DRBD)
     100G "Do not use" primary (to be later used for DRBD)
```

The first two are no problem but i cant find the correct way to create two empty partitions of 100G which i can use for DRBD.

Is there someone that can give me a hint?

Thanks alot!
Remco